# UseEffect with vanilla js

Tags: javascript

When there is a change in my code, I try to rewrite the UseEffect function to detect it, but I could not solve some parts at all. Could you please help me on how to solve these problems?

My Current Code:

```js
const app = document.getElementById('app');

const useEffect = (HandleFunction, Values) =>
  Values.forEach((Value) =>
    Object.defineProperty(window, Value, {
      get() {
        return this._currentValue;
      },
      set(v) {
        if (v === this._currentValue) return;
        this._currentValue = v;
        HandleFunction(this._currentValue);
      },
      configurable: true,
    })
  );

const IncreaseButton = document.querySelector('p.increase');

IncreaseButton.addEventListener('click', IncreaseButtonHandler);

s = 0;

useEffect(
  function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
  ['s']
);

function IncreaseButtonHandler(event) {
  s = s + 1;
}
```

When i press the button the value is logged in console sucessfully.

But i need check values like original react,

```js
useEffect(
  function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
  [s]
);
```

but i can't find the solution.

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is. React's useEffect function is intimately tied in with the react render lifecycle (first, something must call setState, which triggers a cascade of rerenders, and during that the useEffect can compare values from this render and the previous render). Are you planning to implement a render lifecycle of your own? I'm guessing not, so what are the features that your useEffect needs to have?

Comment: React checks if the old dependency array have the same items as the new one on every render. Your `useEffect` do something else and works in different way.

Comment: I'm not using react, i only need a function like useEffect for detect value changes

Comment: `i only need a function like useEffect for detect value changes` What are the requirements for this function? P.S, react's useEffect is not really responsible for detecting changes, that's what `setState` is for. useEffect's dependency array is about *ignoring* changes.

Comment: For example, when a variable value is changed in the code, I want to control it directly over the variable value, not with events. But when looping with SetInterval, resource usage is very high.

Comment: What is missing then? You said `When i press the button the value is logged in console sucessfully.`, so doesn't that mean it's working? The only problem you identified is that your code takes an array of strings, not an array of values. That's true, but that's necessary to do the code that you've written. React's useEffect does something completely different than what you're trying to do, so you should not be trying to copy useEffect.